# bash_profile unable to open

Tags: passenger, homebrew, bash

I cannot open ~/.bash_profile
I've types ls -la and it is listed with all the other system files, except the words bash_profile are in red. I've checkout permissions and chmod worked fine, but when I type open ~/.bash_profile this is what happened: 
Another terminal window automatically pops up with this:

```
Last login: Mon Jun  3 23:14:18 on ttys001
/Users/jessicashu/.bash_profile ; exit;
-bash: /usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d/git-completion.bash: No such file or directory
Jessicas-MacBook-Pro:~ jessicashu$ /Users/jessicashu/.bash_profile ; exit;
/Users/jessicashu/.bash_profile: line 14: /usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d/git-    completion.bash: No such file or directory
logout

[Process completed]
```

please help! this all started with a problem with passenger. I use rails and rvm.

edit: I noticed I can open this fine with sublime from terminal. Still, this is a weird error and I'd like to know why; it might help me figure out why I am having so many other weird errors around the same time I used passenger

Answer (score 1):

The error message says that the file `/usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d/git-completion.bash` isn't there. You can provide this file, or remove line 14 from your `.bash_profile`.